# remove black line after the last item in ListView

Tags: android, listview, layout

Hello i have a listview conatins items , however i have a black line after the last element in the list view can i remove it , thanks for your time .

[image]

Comment: That shouldn't really be there. Can you show us your layout XML for both the `ListView` and its items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you need to use this

```
android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#attr_android:footerDividersEnabled